# Mod tool Convert to Question

Tags: feature-request

It'd be nice if there was a mod tool "Convert to Question" similar to "Convert to Comment" that would delete the answer and convert to a new post.

Comment: I totally agree! Maybe post this one to meta.stackexchange.com too? I'd support it all the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it won't happen, several dupes in meta all linking back to this:
[Convert non-answers into new questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/convert-non-answers-into-new-questions)